# The given ODE can be solved using separation of variables $ (x-y)dx+(x+y)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

> The given ODE can be solved using separation of variables
> $$ (x-y)dx+(x+y)dy=0$$

> $(1)$ yes

> $(2)$ no

Firstly by eyes it cannot be done like that but if I do the substitution $y=vx$ then it can be solved using separation of variables.

So what my answer should be? Yes or no?

Comment: In the immediate sense, no. After a substitution, there are several ways. One other is using polar coordinates, seeing the pattern $(x\,dx+y\,dy) + (x\,dy-y\,dx)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

An Ode that can be solved by separation of variable has the form:
$$y'=f(y)g(x)$$
$$\dfrac {dy}{f(y)}= {g(x)} dx$$
For your ODE you need to substitute first $y=vx$ to transform it into a separable DE. Since the DE is homogeneous. So the correct answer should be no.